# How can I force a new mail message to be plain text using the mailto: URI?

Tags: html, email, mailto

Using notification emails as part of a workflow. The notification contains action buttons are mailto: links that generate a message for the notified user to send their preferred action back to the server. For some of these actions I need to capture comments from the first line of the email.

Currently the new mail window in MS Outlook is being generated in HTML mode. When we receive the email the comment is recorded as a seemingly random alphanumeric string. If I manually select 'plain text' in the MS Outlook new message window, we get the comments recorded as intended.

Is there a way to use the mailto: URI to force the email to send as plain text rather than HTML?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Nothing in [the protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) allows you to suggest the content-type of the email created.

> The user agent interpreting a mailto URL SHOULD choose not to
> create    a message if any of the headers are considered dangerous; it
> may also    choose to create a message with only a subset of the
> headers given in    the URL.  Only the Subject, Keywords, and Body
> headers are believed    to be both safe and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Quentin. My research was starting to suggest that, but good to have it confirmed.